# What pattern or approach should be used for a pattern matching rules engine

Tags: design-patterns, matching, rule-engine

I'm looking for a proper way/approach/pattern for the following problem:
I have a long log-file with error messages (errorID, errortype, timestamps for begin and end of error, plus additional info about the error) stored in a relational DB-table. An error-message, ie. a log-entry, might have a header like this:

[ErrorID, Errortype, arrived, ended, velocity, heat, ...]

-) ErrorID: unique

-) ErrorType: could be "too fast" for example

-) arrived: when the error occured

-) ended: when the error ended

-) velocity, heat, ... : eg. 100km/h and 100 degrees.

There could be additional fields, but lets keep it simple. Additional field just give a little more information about the error.

Most of these rows/error messages are unimportant but certain combinations of messages are important, lets say a few 100 patterns of error messages are important (timewise and content-of-the-message-wise), e.g.:

eg.1) if message x appears y times within a certain time interval I want find it (regardless of other messages in-between)

eg.2) message z is important by itself and I want to find it

eg.3) a block of x messeges of type y have the same timestamp and I want to find them

This is essentially pattern matching, where each occurence of the pattern would be returned with the patternID and the timestamp of the first message in the pattern (or the timeinterval of all the messages). I could code this easily with a lot of if-statements for each pattern I want to find (eg. filter the logs and display if something was found), but this is not scaleable and gets messy pretty fast.

Factory+AbstractFactory-pattern would be my first approach (Abstract for the general type of pattern, the normal factory for the specific implementation), but I would need a factory for each pattern and that just creates hundreds of classes, similarly the strategy pattern. I also found that there are things called rules engines, but from what I found they are not flexible enough to capture my problem easily.

Any suggestions for a good way capture this problem (no software, I want to code it on my own)?

Comment: 1. give a more precise description of your data file (header and example data)

Comment: 2. if you have 3 different questions, make 3 different questions out of this one

Comment: 3. generally try to be more precise and less verbose. imagine you are talking to coding machines here, who need input to solve a single, precisely specified coding problem. do not thing here are humans that you cna talk to for a while to make them slowly understand what you want and then at some point they start solving your problems and you review them and tell them wehre they misunderstood you and so on.

Comment: @hoijui: I updated the question to include a sample header for the log-table. It's basically one question: how can one manage and detect various combinations of specific log-message-types that may be spread over time in a large log-table.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern, which should help you to implement your rules as different strategies with uniform interface.

Now you can read your log-messages one-by-one and pass to all rules. You can check [Chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern, especially if the same log message can trigger different rules and you'd like to avoid this. Chain or responsibility can allow you to *chain* your rules in priority order, so when more important rule is triggered it stops passing the message down the chain.

I don't see how Abstract Factory is applicable here, maybe you haven't provided enough details. [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) is designed to create a *family* of related objects, and your `rules` are not such a family, they are different implementation of same abstract object, a `rule`.

Answer (score 0):

## Patterns

If I were you, I would use the following combination of patterns *specifically for data pre-processing*.

Since you have a large file to deal with, I assume you can not fit it into memory. While you can use a naive stream-based file reading process, it seems to limiting here. If you decide that for your code it is better to be able to read the file start-to-end *with occasional returns* (for subproblem #1), I'd implement a custom [`Iterator`](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/iterator) that encapsulates this logic. The would not be a normal iterator which only goes start-to-end, so in addition to `first()`, `next()`, `isEndReached()` functions, a similar set of functions is needed for the reverse direction of iteration (`previous()`, `isBeginningReached()`, and maybe `last()`).

As the iterator visits the line log entries, it will need to parse them in `LogEntry` objects. Depending on how complex and how stable the line format is, you may want to use a simple `Factory` or a bit more flexible [`Builder`](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder) or even a heavy parser ([`Interpreter`](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/interpreter)).

The most trivial problem(s) can then be solved by having a collection of Matchers, each detecting entries that fall into a specific category of interest. In the most naive implementation such a pattern could be a simple predicate that accepts a `LogEntry` object.

## Algorithms and Approaches

> if message x appears y times within a certain time interval I want find it (regardless of other messages in-between)

In my opinion, this kind of problem is pretty hard to solve with an algorithms. More importantly, you **will** want to search for something completely different in the future. So, I would not try to hard-code all those custom Macthers which do the work.

Instead, I would store the `LogEntry` collection into a SQL database. Why so? Well after doing that, you can **easily and efficiently query this data in the ways you haven't thought about**. It's easy to write SQL-queries, it's not easy to code a new Matcher which traverses tons of records back-and-force, right? This is actually not my own idea -- this is what we did when I worked for a huge IT monster.

So, coming back to the original Problem #1, the final solution might looks as simple as this

```
SELECT Message, COUNT(Message)
FROM LogEntries
WHERE
  '2017-01-01T00:00:00' >= TimeStamp AND TimeStamp <= '2017-01-02T00:00:00'
GROUP BY
  Message
HAVING
  COUNT(Message) > 5
```